# Unable to sync all users from Azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

My application(registered in AD) lists all the users alphabetically.But i am not able to sync users starting with R and beyond

Comment: You need to show some code so we can say what might be the problem. One thing that could be the problem is that the API will give you a page of users at a time, and you have to make another request to get more.

Comment: Are you syncing to Windows AD? If so what method are you using? PTA? ADFS?